# Is there a way to override and add some implicits to a method?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following method:

```
class TestBase {
  def base(value: Int) = println(value)
}
```

Now, I wanted to override it and add some function, performing side-effect which is supposed to bring into scope by caller. I mean caller will decide what side effect to add. I tried it like this:

```
class TestDerived extends TestBase{
  override def base(value: Int)(implicit ev : Int => Unit) = println("Overriden") 
                           //Error, Method 'base' overrides nothing
}
```

But this code refuses to compile. I suspected, but didn't know fore sure if `implicits` are part of method's signature. So, is there any other way to let caller provide their own version of side-effect function. The reason I cannot just add implicit parameter to a base class is that I use `akka.Actor` and I cannot modify signature of `akka.actor.receive: Receive`.

Comment: In Scala and Java, different signatures means different methods since your method has a different signature it can not override the other method.

Comment: Just curious if you able to override actor recevie with implicit, how will you call it? you send message to actor with tell or ask and then receive is called by akka itself.

Comment: @FatihDonmez Well I just provided the value for the implicit with import. What's wrong?

Comment: if you provide it with import than you don't need to change method signature, it can be used inside of receive method. Making method to accept implicit means that when it called obj.method it can get some other stuff implicitly. In this case you're not directly calling actor recevie, which means there's nothing like actorRef.recevie. You do actorRef ! stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is posible

If I call the derived function by using base pointer:

```
val o: TestBase = new TestDerived
o.base(1)
```

Since the implicit parameter is added by compiler while compiling, but here the compiler only lookup the base function signature, so the compiler will not generate the implicit parameter.

Comment: The exact invocation, in my case, result in calling the `TestDerived` implementation and throws due to no implicit in the scope.

Comment: @sebszyller would you please paste full test code ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve the same behaviour, but not through overriding the method. You have a couple of options:

**1. Move the implicit to the constructor**

```
class TestDerived()(implicit ev: Int => Unit) extends TestBase {
  override def base(value: Int) {
    println("Overriden") 
  }
}
```

**2. Wrap the base method in another method**

```
class TestDerived() extends TestBase {

  def base2(value: Int)(implicit ev: Int => Unit): Unit = {
    // implement whatever logic you want here.
    ev(base(value))
  }
}
```

Comment: Having implicit in the constructor seems a little strange as it limits you from choosing any other implicit later on.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Just highlighting-ing possible options, it's not a common use case but it's not the most uncommon either.